# Accessing object in parent user control from child user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a user control, Parent.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Parent.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="Parent" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="Child" Src="~/Child.ascx" %>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hfId" runat="server" />

<cc:Child ID="child1" runat="server" />
```

My child control Child.ascx contains a button, and in the code-behind I'd like to access the value of the hidden field `hfId` in the click event of that button

I can't use a user control attribute and set it on `Page_Load` because the value of that hidden field is changing through jQuery events in the Parent.ascx control

Comment: The jquery events change the value after the response has been written out to the client. If you want to get the value of it in javascript client side from the control, then perhaps you could pass it the client id or a reference to the hidden field itself on initialization of the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code to access the hidden field from the child control. `this.Parent` will give the parent control & use `FindControl` to find the control by ID.

```
HiddenField hfID = this.Parent.FindControl("hfId") as HiddenField;
string hiddenvalue = hfID.Value;
```

If you change the value of the hidden field on page load, then on button click, the updated value gets reflected.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the control from the child using:

```
var hfId = (HiddenField)NamingContainer.FindControl("hfId");
```

Comment: I don't like this solution because a. it doesn't make sense if he's talking about after the javascript has executed and b. somebody editing the Page would never know they need to also modify this control.